# how to find coordinates of the rectangles from image in python with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have some imperfect rectangles in the image, I need set of coordinates for each rectangle in python using opencv

I have tried Canny edge detection and the used findContours but it's giving more coordinates than required because rectangles are not having straight lines

I have read similar questions but I am not getting correct results. Can you please provide solution with code?

original image
[image: original]
After Canny edge detection
[image: Canny edge detection]

How to get only inner borders of rectangles from Canny Edges? As there is double border for each rectangles, it's giving more number of rectangles than required.

```
image = cv2.imread(OUTPUT_FILE)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.blur(gray, (5,5))

kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

edged = cv2.Canny(closing, 30, 200)
cv2.imshow("Canny", edged)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print(len(contours))

for c in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)

    for p in box:
        pt = (p[0],p[1])
        plt.scatter(p[0],p[1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: The 12 set of coordinates are the 10 small rectangles and the two large outer ones?

Comment: yes, correct...and with this code I am getting multiple coordinates for a single rectangle as you can see in plotted image

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem could be solved using findContours(), depending on your version of OpenCV, it returns several values, but one of them is always **contours**, which is a list of all points of contour. One bit of advice that I often use is that I calculate the centroid of all contour points. That means that I sum all points along **x** coordinate sum them and divide by the length of the contour list for **this specific contour**, and do the same for **y** coordinate.

You can also use [boundingRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) function, which will give you x,y coordinates of top left corner of the bounding box, as well as its width and height. In a link above, you can find a really nice tutorial on the topic. I think that this function suits better to your problem.

Good luck!